# Diagonally divided table cell

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Diagonal lines in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell)

I'd like to include a table of numbers in my document. Those numbers are defined by two parameters *n* and *k*, and I'd like to achieve a presentation similar to what Comtet did in "Advanced Combinatorics". More precisely, I'm interested in dividing the top-left cell to include both *n* and *k*, as he did in the example below:

[image]

How do I do that?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of a newer questions: the linked one has a better overall answer, I feel. (Tikz gives an exact solution, which `slashbox` does not.)

Comment: @JosephWright Would it make sense to merge these questions?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the `slashbox` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
 \backslashbox{n}{k} & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to connect certain cells within the table with arrows and so an, it might be easier to use tikz. Here is a somehow evil hack to get a slashbox in a matrix of nodes. I am sure this can be done much better by someone else

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

%\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
 %\backslashbox{n}{k} & 0 & 1\\\hline
%0 & 1 & 2 \\
%\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix (mymatrix) [matrix of nodes,
            nodes in empty cells,
%text depth=.5ex,
text height=1.5ex,
text width=1.5ex
            ]
{
\begin{scope} \tikz\node[overlay] at (-.8ex,-0.4ex){\footnotesize n};\tikz\node[overlay] at (1ex,0.5ex){\footnotesize k}; \end{scope} & 2 & 3 & 8\\\hline
4 & |[fill=blue!10]|5 & 6 & 4\\
7 & 8 & 9 & 0\\
10 & 11 & 12 & |[fill=blue!10]|1\\
};
%vertical and diagonal line
\draw (mymatrix-1-2.north west) -- (mymatrix-4-2.south west);
\draw (mymatrix-1-1.north west) -- (mymatrix-1-1.south east);%n k diagonal line

%connection between nodes
\draw[->] (mymatrix-2-2) to [bend right=25] (mymatrix-4-4.north west);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I like the TikZ version better, although it probably does too much. On the other hand, we proved some formulae for computing parts of the table, and what you provide may come in handy if we decide to highlight those parts.

Comment: I have added a comment in the code. basically I created a line from the north west corner of cell (1,1) to the south east corner of cell (1,1). This approach has a few disadvantages as it is sensitive to column with changes. That is why I was hoping someone has better solution

Comment: I guess what confused me was your comment "vertical **and horizonal** lines"...should be "and diagonal" since the horizontal is created right after the scope

Comment: true indeed, i changes that

Comment: It did not look so good anymore when I started modifying it. One suggestion I have is to replace the first `\hline` with a path, and then use `\coordinate` to build the diagonal that starts at the intersection of that path with the path that shows the first column. The diagonal will then "resist" changes. However, that replacement for `\hline` isn't so straight, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: It seems there is no `slashbox` in TeXlive 2016 but there is an alternative package called `diagbox`.

Answer (score 10):

```
\input eplain
\vbox{\offinterlineskip
\halign{\tabskip1em
  $\phantom{\Big)}#$&\vrule#&&\hfil$#$\hfil\cr
  \sarrowlength=1.5em
  \hidewidth\matrix{\sline(1,-1)\lft{n}\rt{k}}\hidewidth
    && 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \cdots \cr
  \noalign{\hrule}
  0 && 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vdots \cr
  1 && 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cr
  2 && 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
  3 && 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
  4 && 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr
  5 && 1 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 1 & 0 \cr
  \vdots && \cdots \cr
}}\bye
```

[image]
It could use some better spacing, but the idea is there.

Comment: @morbusg: I'm not the downvoter, but I do think that your post doesn't answer the question: The OP explicitely asked for a _table_.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: under the hood, it *is* a table ;-)

Comment: @morbusg: Well, I see you mean this as a joke, but I still don't see how your answer can be of help to the OP.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: It's not a joke in the sense that bordermatrix expands to "initialized halign" (as I'm sure you know). However, what I meant is that: *"If your data can be thought of as a matrix (which seemed to me to possibly be the case), here's a solution"*, without **knowing** if that is the case. Sometimes it may be beneficial to suggest other ways to look at your data. I'm not necessarily saying it is beneficial here.

Comment: @morbusg: It was clear to me that part of your joke was serious and correct. And clearly, a bordermatrix is the correct _data structure_ for the OP's data. However, he want's to _display_ his data in a table! (And also I think that this is a good idea.)

Comment: @morbusg: Looks much more like an answer now. The main problem I still see is the inflexible backslash that doesn't look great.

Comment: I give up, Mr.~@Vogt: a honest table it is.

Comment: @morbusg: +1; the diagonal line is still not optimal, but this looks very much like an answer to the question now.

Comment: @morbusg +1: table, indeed.