# LaTeX table cell with a diagonal line and 2 sub cells

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diagonally divided table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/diagonally-divided-table-cell)
>   [Diagonal lines in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell)

I'd like to have a LaTeX table, where the top left cell marks what the headers are to the right and also mark what the descriptors are downwards.

For this I'd like to have the upper left table cell be "split" diagonally, (from top left of cell to bottom right) by drawing a line and above that line, I'd like to place the name of headings to the right, and below the headings of the descriptors downwards.

Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: See [diagonal lines in table cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell)

Answer (score 56):

You can use the [`slashbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/slashbox) to do this. The following minimal example was taken directly from the [examples page](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/slashbox/slashbox.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l||*{5}{c|}}\hline
\backslashbox{Room}{Date}
&\makebox[3em]{5/31}&\makebox[3em]{6/1}&\makebox[3em]{6/2}
&\makebox[3em]{6/3}&\makebox[3em]{6/4}\\\hline\hline
Meeting Room &&&&&\\\hline
Auditorium &&&&&\\\hline
Seminar Room &&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Slashbox]​

Comment: `slashbox` has been superceded by `diagbox`. See 
https://ctan.org/pkg/diagbox