# Diagonal line for a table with multiple rows

Tags: tables, floats, cell

Considering the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/latex-table-cell-with-a-diagonal-line-and-2-sub-cells) of question, I used the slashbox package to draw a diagonal line. But the problem is I have multiple rows in my table and that makes the line not aligned well within the cell corners. It also gives wierd spaces between cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htpc]
\begin{center}
  \centering
  \caption{some table.}
  \label{possibility}
  \begin{footnotesize}

   \adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
           max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  &first  & first  & second  & second & both  & both  & &\\
  &key & key &  key &  key& key & key & none&all\\
\backslashbox{Room}{Date}  &at & at &  at &  at & at & at& & \\
   &d & p &  d & p & d & p & &\\ \hline
  $C_1$&Y & N & N & N & N & N & N &N \\ \hline

  \hline


\end{tabular}
}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I have used the answer presented by @bernard but it gives me `! Use of \line doesn't match its definition` as an error. Not sure if it would happen for others as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `diagbox`, which is more powerful. I improved your table using `makecell` (allows for line breaks and vertical padding in cells). Also, don't use the `center` environment in tables, as it adds unwanted vertical spacing; use `\centering` instead. The placement of the diagonal line is adjusted through the optional argument of `\multirow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption, multirow, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
  \centering
  \caption{some table.}
  \label{possibility}
  \footnotesize\makegapedcells
   \adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
   max width=\textwidth}{
  \begin{tabular}{|*{9}{c|}}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{5.2}[2.3ex]{\diagbox[height=5.17\line]{\rlap{\enspace\raisebox{2ex}{Room}}}{\raisebox{-3.5ex}{Date}}} &\makecell{first\\key} & \makecell{first\\key} & \makecell{second\\key} & \makecell{second\\key} & \makecell{both\\keys} & \makecell{both\\keys}& none&all\\
          & at & at & at & at & at & at & & \\
          & d & p & d & p & d & p & & \\ \hline
    $C₁$ & Y & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Always vote +1 for my friends.

Comment: Why did you comment out the adjustbox?

Comment: @lonesome: Sorry. I did it to see whether the table overflowed the prescribed dimensions, and I forgot to uncomment before posting.

Comment: It also gives error as `! Use of \line doesn't match its definition.`

Comment: I asked about adjustbox just in case if it was a wrong choice.

Comment: I have no idea, because I never used it for tables (it can result in unreadable text within table), and here it doesn't seem to be useful. As to the error you mention, I don't have it. I only  had a warning about an overfull vbox, due to the value of the no of rows in `\multirow`, solved by changing `4` to `5.2`.

Comment: any other unit to use for defining the height of dialogbox?

Comment: Any unit you please. `\line` is supposed to be the interrow spacing in the table.  For vertical spacings I would suggest `ex`, as the number of these should not change much if you decide to change the document font size (ideally, should not change at all).

Comment: so can you replace `[height=5.17\line]` with something to act similarly? should I just use 5.17 as the length?

Comment: Absolutely. Anyway, I had a rough estimate of the value, and it was adjusted by trial and error.

Comment: but it still gives this error when I remove \line that the pt is inserted as a unit which is wrong. More precisely:`! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58831/discussion-between-bernard-and-lonesome).

Comment: still same error for `\line` even I just copy pasted the entire code of yours.

Comment: @lonesome: Do you have the last version (`2.2`) of `diagbox`? It might  be a possibility.

Comment: @Bernard Well, how to find out if the version is 2.2 or not?

Comment: @lonesome: You should find the version in the `.log` file. I obtain this line on my system: `Package: diagbox 2016/12/28 v2.2 Making table heads with diagonal lines`. Other than that, `[height=14ex]` is fine for me.

Comment: aaaa. mine is v2.

Comment: Well, you should update, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
  \centering
  \caption{some table.}
  \label{possibility}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{2cm}*{8}{c}}[vlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
    \hline
    \Block{3-1}{\diagbox{\quad \rule[-5pt]{0pt}{5pt}Room}{\rule{0pt}{15pt}Date\quad}}
    & \Block{}{first\\key}  & \Block{}{first\\key} 
    & \Block{}{second\\key} & \Block{}{second\\key} 
    & \Block{}{both\\keys}  & \Block{}{both\\keys}& none&all\\
          & at & at & at & at & at & at & & \\
          & d & p & d & p & d & p & & \\ \hline
    $C_1$ & Y & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\
    \hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]