# Is it possible to add a diagonal line or slashbox to a very simple template of a table?

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable, tabularx

I have a very simple template of a table

[image]

I would like to add a slashbox at the top **left** corner (entry|item), similar to this post [LaTeX table cell with a diagonal line and 2 sub cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/latex-table-cell-with-a-diagonal-line-and-2-sub-cells)

However, I have tried to add their code on top of the code below, yet I was not able to make it work.

Can someone provide a simple solution that creates a slashbox / diagonal line for this table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{steinmetz}                           
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}                 
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{sidecap}                              
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 
\setlength{\footskip}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \centering\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
        \hline
          & entry 1 &  entry 2 & entry 3 &  entry 4 \\
        \hline
        item 1 & $\%$ & $\%$  & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        \hline
        item 2 & $\%$  & $\%$  & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        \hline
        item 3  & $\%$ & $\%$  & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        \hline
        item 4 & $\%$ & $\%$  & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\\
\end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: are you sure you want to globally do `\everymath{\displaystyle}` ?(it makes inline math essentially unusable as inline math, although it can be useful for some special situations where you need to use inline math for technical reasons but want it to look like display

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I might have added that line as a quick fix for something a long time ago. I am not sure what this line does anymore. it makes inline math essentially unusable? Oh that sounds bad

Comment: Do you need text to appear in the slashbox as in your linked example? Or just the diagonal line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the `diagbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array, diagbox}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||*{4}{p{2cm}|}}
        \hline
        \diagbox[innerwidth = 3cm, height = 4ex]{}{} & entry 1 & entry 2 & entry 3 & entry 4 \\
        \hline
        item 1 & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        \hline
        item 2 & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        \hline
        item 3 & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        \hline
        item 4 & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabualar}` of `nicematrix`, you do need adjustment to the command `\diagbox` (in fact, it's a command `\diagbox` provided by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ |p{3cm}||*{4}{p{2cm}|}}[hvlines]
        \diagbox{}{} & entry 1 & entry 2 & entry 3 & entry 4 \\
        item 1 & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        item 2 & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        item 3 & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$\\
        item 4 & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$ & $\%$\\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]