# How to split a table cell diagonally in lyx?

Tags: tables, lyx

I have a table where I want to split the top left cell in 2 diagonally, as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/latex-table-cell-with-a-diagonal-line-and-2-sub-cells). All the answers I have found online are latex code, but I only know how to use Lyx. Is there a way to do it in Lyx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LyX you can enter LaTeX code.

Go to the menu item Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble, and insert

```
\usepackage{diagbox}
```

Then in the topleft cell, choose the menu item Insert > TeX Code and enter

```
\diagbox{xxx}{yyy}
```

(whatever you want there).