# Is it possible to create a table with two entries in one cell separated by 45 degree line?

Tags: tables

I want to create a table like the below picture in LaTeX. 
Does anyone tried this before? Can you introduce how to create such 
a table?

The problem is that I don't know to how create the slash line separating "Name" and "Group" fields.

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/

Comment: You have the `slashbox` and `diagbox` packages for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need cells *strictly squares* you can try

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array} % Improves `tabular` and `array` environments
\usepackage{pict2e} % Allows \linethickness{...} in diagonal lines
\usepackage{slashbox} % Defines \backslashbox{..}{..}
\begin{document}
\linethickness{1pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \backslashbox{Group}{Name} & Henry & John \\ \hline
                G1             &   1   &  0   \\ \hline
                G2             &   1   &  1   \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

And you gets

[image]

If you wants something like your image can try `tikz`.