# Backslash in tables: end in corner

Tags: tables

Is it possible to end the backslash in the left upper corner of the table?
[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
$c\backslash a$&0&1\\\hline
0&&\\
1&&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do the answers here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell solve your problem?

Comment: So there is no solution without using TikZ?

Comment: You could use the `makecell` package. I think an example is already provided in one of the older answers. Take a look to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/diagonally-divided-table-cell for even another approach

Comment: IIRC there's the `diagbox` package…

Comment: Your link give a possibility using the slashbox package. But if I do this, I get the error 'slachbox.sty not found'. Can you maybe post a little example using makecell or diagbox?

Comment: The best would be avoiding the diagonal to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}

\diaghead(-2,1){aaaaaaa}%
{b}{a}&
0&1\\\hline

0&&\\
1&&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

syntax is: `\diaghead(H ratio,V ratio){Text set for column widthi}{First head}{Second head}` (makecell manual section 7)

[image]

(TikZ solutions look much better in my opinion)

Comment: What is H ratio,V ratio meaning? Unclear.

Comment: @pzorba75 It changes the orientation of the diagonal line. Just try with different values or check the manual