# Diagonal line through a cell in a table

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|llll}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$00$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$01$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$10$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$11$} \\ \hline
$00$ & $\frac{729}{1000}$ & $\frac{27}{5000}$ & $\frac{27}{10000}$ & $\frac{1}{10000}$ \\
$01$ & $\frac{81}{1000}$ & $\frac{243}{5000}$ & $\frac{3}{10000}$ & $\frac{9}{10000}$ \\
$10$ & $\frac{81}{1000}$ & $\frac{3}{5000}$ & $\frac{243}{10000}$ & $\frac{9}{1000}$ \\
$11$ & $\frac{9}{1000}$ & $\frac{27}{5000}$ & $\frac{27}{1000}$ & $\frac{81}{10000}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

In the empty upper left cell, I want to include a diagonal line (left to right), with "w" on the bottom and "v" on the top. How can I do this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you really want to add such a diagonally split cell, take a look at the `diagbox` package.

Comment: See also: [Diagonally divided table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7262/134144), [Diagonal lines in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17745/134144)